# Sequelize: how to set PK of join table as pair of foreign keys to be able to use save() on the join table instance without triggering 'no PK error'?

Tags: sequelize.js

How to make Sequelize treat foreign keys of join table as composite primary key? I thought that it is done by default, but when I tried to save my `UserMenuItem` instance (which is join table between `User` and `MenuItem`),  got this error: `Error: You attempted to save an instance with no primary key, this is not allowed since it would result in a global update`.

My associations are defined as follows:

```
 models.User.hasMany(models.UserMenuItem, { foreignKey: 'userID', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
 models.UserMenuItem.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userID', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });

 models.MenuItem.hasMany(models.UserMenuItem, { foreignKey: 'menuItemID', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
 models.UserMenuItem.belongsTo(models.MenuItem, { foreignKey: 'menuItemID', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });

 models.MenuItem.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: models.UserMenuItem, foreignKey: 'menuItemID', onDelete: 'CASCADE' }); // I tried adding "otherKey: 'userID'" as well
 models.User.belongsToMany(models.MenuItem, { through: models.UserMenuItem, foreignKey: 'userID', onDelete: 'CASCADE' }); I tried adding "otherKey: 'menuItemID'" as well
```

I'm not including models definitions as I don't think they are relevant. `User` and `MenuItem` have a PK called `ID` and the join table has some additional data fields except for FKs.

Is it at all possible, or do I have to add unnecessary PK to the join table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define composite primary key.

> Belongs-To-Many creates a unique key when primary key is not present on through model. This unique key name can be overridden using uniqueKey option.

See [BelngToMany in official docs](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Another disappointment from Sequelize. I'll add the PK separately then...

Answer (score 1):

Even I had this same situation I got it solved by passing id whenever we save the model instance.